# Can't assign the proper value on picked type

Tags: typescript

When I tried something like this in Typescript...

```js
interface SomeType {
  size: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
  other: any;
}

let size: Pick<SomeType, 'size'> = 'sm';
```

I got this error. Is this an expected error???

`Type '"sm"' is not assignable to type 'Pick<SomeType, "size">'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pick<SomeType, 'size'>` will create an object type with the property `size`, basically the same as `{ size: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'; }`.

You are probably looking for an type index query:

```
interface SomeType {
    size: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
    other: any;
}

let size: SomeType['size'] = 'sm'; //ok
```

Answer (score 2):

from the definition of Pick

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: T[P]; }
```

what type you have is

```
{ size: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'; }
```

so you has to do

```
let size: Pick<SomeType, 'size'> = { size: 'sm' };
```